# Echo base URL() rduplicates url again in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, url

When I Echo base URL inside href tag it duplicates again in codeigniter.
In config.php base , I set base url as

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.mysite.in/';
```

And autoload Url in autoload.php

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/fav-icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

When I inspect abpove href it shows as
[image]

`<img` tag is also missing

Answer (score 0):

First : you need to add activate url in autoload.php file

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Second : you need to add the url in the config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.mysite.in';
```

Third you need to add the code like this

```
<?php echo base_url("assets/img/fav-icons/apple-touch-icon.png"); ?>
```

[Sample on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqk0K.jpg)